# Under what conditions can one deloop the free loop fibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration, loop-spaces

Inspired by the MO question [Homotopy extension of $E_\infty$-spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349682/41291).

Sending a map $f:S^1\to X$ to $f(\text{basepoint})$ gives a fibration $\Lambda X\to X$ with fiber $\Omega X$, where $\Lambda X$ is the free loop space of $X$ and $\Omega X$ is the based loop space of $X$.

On the other hand, a basepoint preserving map $e:X\to X$ gives a fibration $F_e\to X$ with fiber $\Omega X$ too, where $F_e$ is the homotopy fiber of $e$, i. e. the space of pairs $(x,p)$ where $x\in X$ and $p:[0,1]\to X$ is a path with $p(0)$ the basepoint and $p(1)=e(x)$.

For which $X$ does there exist an $e$ with fibrewise equivalence between $F_e$ and $\Lambda X$?

(Note that if one replaces the free loop fibration with the path fibration $PX\to X$ the answer is easily "all $X$": in that case $e$ can be taken the identity map.)

Comment: What is $\Lambda X$? What is $F_e$?

Comment: @ConnorMalin Added definitions

Comment: In other words, you are asking when $\Lambda X \rightarrow X$ is a principal fibration?

Comment: @ConnorMalin I don't know whether what I am asking is equivalent to that.

Comment: However what you said makes me think of a possible answer. The fibration $\Lambda X\to X$ has a section. If a principal fibration has a section it is trivial. Now I believe that if $e$ in question exists then because of the section of $\Lambda X\to X$ this $e$ must factor through $PX$, hence be homotopic to a constant map. This would imply that the free loop fibration is trivial.